Update a bitly link with API using AMPScript in SMS
We are using custom back-half links in Bitly to redirect to a CloudPage for capturing clicks in SMS campaigns. However, we encountered an issue: Bitly only accepts static links. This means that if I generate a CloudPage link with subscriber data and add it to the bitly link, all clicks will be registered under that specific subscriber.
To address this, I am attempting to use the Bitly API. The goal is to update the Bitly link with the custom back-half with a new long_url based on the dynamic CloudPage URL.
According to bit.ly documentation, the process involves two steps:

Shorten the CloudPage URL using the /v4/shorten endpoint (ACHIEVED)
Send a PATCH request to the /v4/custom_bitlinks endpoint to update the
link

However, I believe there is no HTTP PATCH method available in AMPScript, only POST and GET. Is there a way to achieve this?
Here is the code I used to shorten the CloudPage URL in SMS:
%%[ VAR @SubKey, @PhoneNumber, @SourceSMS, @CloudPage, @bitlyUrl, @ShortLink, @bitlyToken, @bitlyPage, @contentType, @additionalHeaderName, @additionalHeaderValue, @customPage

SET @SubKey = AttributeValue("SubscriberKey") 
SET @PhoneNumber = AttributeValue("PhoneNumber") 
SET @SourceSMS = "TestLink"

SET @bitlyToken = [TOKEN] 
SET @bitlyPage = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten' 
SET @contentType = 'application/json' 
SET @additionalHeaderName = 'Authorization' 
SET @additionalHeaderValue = concat('Bearer ',@bitlyToken)

SET @cloudpage = CloudPagesURL([Page Identifier],'SubscriberKey',@SubKey,'PhoneNumber',@PhoneNumber,'SourceSMS',@SourceSMS) 
SET @link = URLEncode(@cloudpage)

SET @content = concat('{"long_url": "',@link,'"}')

SET @request = HTTPPost(@bitlyPage, @contentType, @content, @response, @additionalHeaderName, @additionalHeaderValue)

]%%{{.datasource response type=variable}}{{.data}}{ "target" : "@response" }{{/data}}{{link}}{{/datasource}}

We want to keep the custom back-half to keep our branding. We just want to make its redirect personalized based on the subscriber parameters.
I would appreciate any help. Thank you so much.

It seems the best way for this is that you shorten the link without using customized back-half

I am not sure if am getting the need to use this PATCH request. I think you should be able to prepare a unique static link per subscriber and then execute an API call to Bitly to shorten it. For example, you have 10 subscribers and you will have 10 separate Bitly.
